# Python extract multiline comment from .py file

Tags: python

Hi all I've seen several solutions to extracting python comments using tokenizer and looking for

```
tokenize.COMMENT
```

However, I can't find any example of how to do it for multiline comment. For example consider the following readme.py file

```
"""
multiline comment above class read me
read me too
"""
# dont read mee
class TestComment:
    """
        multiline inside class
    """
    def aFunc(self):
        pass
```

How can I extract the contents of mulitline comments like the example above?

Comment: As far as a tokenizer would go, those are multiline string literals, not comments.

Comment: docstring was excluded from the tokenize library but if you miss the ending `"""` it throws an exception. Interesting, they did handle the exception. `459         if contstr:                            # continued string
    460             if not line:
--> 461                 raise TokenError("EOF in multi-line string", strstart)
    462             endmatch = endprog.match(line)
    463             if endmatch:

TokenError: ('EOF in multi-line string', (13, 0))`

Answer (score 2):

tokenize.COMMENT can be used for comments (that begins with #), not for multiline strings literal or docstrings.

However, you can use this regex in order to extract the multiline strings from your example:

```
import re

file = "file.py"

with open(file, "r") as f:
    content = f.read()

p = re.compile('(?:""")(.*?)(?:""")', re.DOTALL)
result = p.findall(content)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['\nmultiline comment above class read me\nread me too\n', '\n        multiline inside class\n    ']
```

If you want to keep the """, just use capturing groups instead of non-capturing groups : `(""")` instead of `(?:""")`.

Using re.DOTALL is important, it allows the dot `.` to match any character *including a newline*.

**A little warning:**

Please note that as @edusanketd said in comment, this regex will match triple quotes used inside regular strings or single line comments too. So, this regex is not the panacea: if all your python files are structured as in your example (`"""` are used ONLY for multilines strings), it will be fine, but if you have some files that use `"""` for other purposes (like triple quote strings used inside regular strings) their wil be some "errors".

Example code showing the limits of this regex :

```
"""
multiline comment above class read me
read me too
"""
# dont read mee
class TestComment:
    """
        multiline inside class
    """
    def aFunc(self):
        pass
a_string = '"""THIS IS NOT A COMMENT"""'
# """dont read me too"""
```

output:

```
['\nmultiline comment above class read me\nread me too\n', '\n        multiline inside class\n    ', 'THIS IS NOT A COMMENT', 'dont read me too']
```

**Some informations about multi-line strings as multi-line comments :**

A tweet form Guido van Rossum :

https://twitter.com/gvanrossum/status/112670605505077248?lang=en

> Python tip: You can use multi-line strings as multi-line comments.
> Unless used as docstrings, they generate no code! :-)

And here is an interesting post from Sean Gillies on this subject:

https://sgillies.net/2017/05/30/python-multi-line-comments-and-triple-quoted-strings.html

Comment: Triple quotes used inside regular strings or single line comments would also get counted this way. That is a major drawback though.

Comment: Yes I agree, this is not the panacea, that's why I mentioned that it could be used *in his example*.  You are right to point it out, I'll edit my post to mention that too.

Answer (score 1):

The so-called `multiline comments` in python are actually treated as `docstrings`. Conventionally a docstring is associated with a class in python. Which can be retrieved using `objname.__doc__`. Here `objname` replaces the immediate `class` or `function` associated with the `docstring`.

For example,

```
class ex:
    """dufvdv"""
    def __init__(self):
        # single line cmt
        """ multiline inside function
        another line """
        pass
```

Using the `__doc__` here goes like:

```
>>> ex.__doc__
'dufvdv'
>>> ex.__init__.__doc__
' multiline inside function\nanother line'
```

I assume you were expecting an inbuilt technique to extract all `multiline comments` from a code, which is not present, to the best of my knowledge.

So, you can use the `__doc__` accordingly.